# Can a backgrounded Android app take screenshots of the currently active screen?

Tags: android, background, screenshot

I'm new to Android development, and I was wondering if there is a way to have an app take a screenshot of the currently active screen, do some processing on the screenshot (which would be internal to the app and temporary; I don't want it in the photo gallery), then communicate with a remote server over the Internet?

I am of course looking for more than a yes or no answer.  An example of an api call or library I could use to do this would be a perfect answer.

The purpose would be to have a program screen scrape another program to recognize some text and use it for updating an online service.

Comment: You want something else than the ShootMe app in Android Market?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that.  Per the other answer, it probably doesn't do what I'm asking, though.

Comment: Having Googled, I stand corrected, but yes I am looking for something different in that I want to be able to implement it myself for a specific purpose and wanted it for non-rooted devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible, at least not on non-rooted devices. This is of course for security reason.

Comment: I will laugh when someone tries to say your answer isn't correct. :) I would bet money they will spend time on it even after you tell them.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take your word for it, if only to take androidworkz money ;)